# Can I roll back my ppa (that I own) on Launchpad for a specific Ubuntu version?

Tags: application-development, launchpad

I own a [project](https://launchpad.net/~vlijm/+archive/ubuntu/orangemetronome/+packages) on Launchpad. I developed it on 16.04, most of the time tested it on 14.04 to check, *except* for the latest version. It turns out the latest version runs fine on 16.04, but not backwards.

I copied the latest version however, assuming it would be all right, already to all Ubuntu versions. I could of course upload the previous version as a newer version, but that seems odd, so:

Can I roll back my project to a previous version, for specific Ubuntu versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to downgrade the version number of an installed package on the user side from your PPA.

The main issue is that some people on 14.04 may have updated your non-functioning package from that PPA. As not all users may already be affected I'd recommend to **immediately remove the buggy package** from the 14.04 PPA to avoid that more people update.

Then you will need some time to debug your package to make it run on both, 16.04, and on 14.04. This release will have a newer version number and can then safely be copied to all series.

If that will not work out easily you will have to release a last version running on 14.04 with a version number +1 from present and release another version with version number +2 for the latest release on 16.04.

Comment: I was afraid so, but the reason is clear. Thanks!

Comment: It is not so much hard work, only juggling with version numbering if you are lazy... ;)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you've deleted the latest version from that series and haven't waited too long, you can use the "Copy packages" page ([here](https://launchpad.net/~vlijm/+archive/ubuntu/orangemetronome/+copy-packages) in the case of this PPA) to copy a previous superseded version back into your PPA; you'll need to change the drop-down to "Superseded" to find it, set the destination PPA to your PPA and the destination series to trusty, and select "Copy existing binaries".

If the previous version is no longer available because you waited too long, then you can still delete the latest version from the affected series and upload a version less than it, e.g. 0.5.4-2.  You can't reuse a version number that's previously been used in that PPA, and you have to do the slightly awkward delete-then-upload thing if you want to make versions go backwards, but it is possible.

(None of this will cause apt clients to automatically downgrade to the lower version number.  Whether you care about that depends on the audience of your PPA.)

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately, I copied the newer version to all Ubuntu versions. The whole trick turned out to be an unnecessary operation, since the error was caused by an incompatible usb headphone on the 14.04, I used occasionally during testing.